# Add a php variable to an html/javascript statement that is converted to php from before

Tags: javascript, php, html, var

This is a php variable that contains some html/javascript code. This is converted to php from before, but I need to add a php variable to it. I have a php variable that is `$user->user_email`. How can I add this variable here: `{this.value =\'\';`? I mean the value shows me the php variable.

```
$button .= '<input type="text" id="parspalpaiddownloads_email_'.$button_id.'" style="font-family: tahoma, verdana; font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px; margin: 5px 0px; padding: 3px 5px; background: #FFF; border: 1px solid #888; width: 200px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; color: #666; min-height:28px" value="'.esc_attr(__('Email', 'parspalpaiddownloads')).'" onfocus="if (this.value == \''.esc_attr(__('Email', 'parspalpaiddownloads')).'\'){this.value =\'\'; this.style.textAlign= \'left\'; this.style.direction= \'ltr\' }" onblur="if (this.value == \'\') {this.value = \''.esc_attr(__('Email', 'parspalpaiddownloads')).'\';  this.style.textAlign= \'right\'; this.style.direction= \'rtl\'}" /></div>';
```

Comment: `this.value =\''.$user->user_email.'\';`

Comment: @Nordenheim This is the right answer

Comment: I somehow missed the answer section and posted it as a comment :)

Comment: You should avoid using extensive inline js, its hard to read and will be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are screening the single quote with `\'`, but you actually have to break the string and inject it with your variable. Your answer is

```
this.value =\''.$user->user_email.'\';
```

And the dots (`.`) join the string parts into one.